# Regex with multiple match does not work

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex:

```
((?i:EUR)( ?)(([0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?)|([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{3})*(,[0-9]+)?)|((\d+)((\.|,)\d+)?))( ?)(?i:Mio|Million|Billion)?)
```

With the regex I want so search for all kinds of numbers. Numbers could contain thousand seperators in english with a "," or in german with a ".". Also decimal numbers are possible (Englisch: "." German: ",").

So far my regex works. There is only one problem. For example:

> the company generated sales of EUR 1.000.000,5 in 2016

The match is:

> the company generated sales of MATCH.000,5 in 2016

The problem is that the first part of the regex `([0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?)` already matches despite the second part `([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{3})*(,[0-9]+)?)` contains a better solution.

Currently I'm trying to fix this problem with the help of a positive lookahead `(^\.(?=[0-9]))`after the first part of the regex like:`([0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?)(^\.(?=[0-9]))`

In sum: `((?i:EUR)( ?)(([0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?)(^\.(?=[0-9]))|([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{3})*(,[0-9]+)?)|((\d+)((\.|,)\d+)?))( ?)(?:Mio|Million|Billion)?)`

But than

> the company generated sales of EUR 1,000,000.5 in 2016

has the following match:

> the company generated sales of MATCH,000.5 in 2016

Has anybody an idea how to use a positive or maybe a negative lookahead in this context so that both problems could be solved?

Comment: How big can the numbers go?

Comment: @Code.IT: I´m not sure. Actually the biggest numbers are around 1.000.000.000.. Does the size matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3madxH/2) uses lookahead to ensure the number contains at least two `,` or two `.`

```
((?i:EUR)\s?
  (?:
    (?=(\d*,){2})[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?
  |
    (?=(\d*\.){2})[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{3})*(,[0-9]+)?
  |
    \d+(?:[.,]\d+)?
  )
\s?(?i:Mio|Million|Billion)?)
```

java code

```
String in = "the company generated sales of EUR 1.000.000,5 in 2016";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    "((?i:EUR)\\s?(?:(?=(\\d*,){2})\\d{1,3}(,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d+)?|(?=(\\d*\\.){2})\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d{3})*(,\\d+)?|\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)?)\\s?(?i:Mio|Million|Billion)?)" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( in );
while ( m.find() ) {
    System.out.println( m.group( 1 ) );
}
```

Comment: regex101 is not in Java Syntax I think

Comment: That works perfectly ! Exactly what I was looking for :-) Costs me nearly 3 hours. Thank you very much !

Comment: fixed a typo in java `[0-9]{1,3}\\d{1,3}` to `\\d{1,3}`

Comment: also to handle numbers with only one `,` or `.` followed by one `.` or `,`: `(?=(\\d*,){2})` should be changed by `(?=\\d+,[\\d,]+\\.\\d)` and `(?=(\\d*\\.){2})` by `(?=\\d+\\.[\\d.]+,\\d)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe: `^([0-9]{0,3}((\,|\.)[0-9]{3})*)((\,|\.)[0-9]*){0,1}`

Comment: While this regexp may have the requested behaviour, it would be better to provide some explanation anyway. Best regards

Comment: I just answered what was questioned. I don't think I am able to explain the whole regex concept and functions like: with postivie, false, negativ, look behind, around, .... Best would be: Buy a book or search for a training online.

Comment: Since you answer with "maybe", you should point what you have changed compared to what they (the asking person) initially tried. Otherwise this is just a "blind guess answer" which is frowned upon at SO. Sure, you don't have to explain basics, except for those which are directly connected to what they missed in their attempts. Best regards